# Can I use a single json file to create a n number of instances of different classes?

Tags: c#, json, class

Is possible to create (from the example below), lets say, 2 instances of Animal and 3 instances of Flower based on data from a single json file?

Example code:

```
class Nature
{
    // do something with a specific json file
    class Animal
    {
        string id;
        bool isMammal;
    }

    class Flower
    {
        string id;
        int numberOfPetals;
    }
}
```

Expected result:

- An x amount of instances of Animal
- An y amount of instances of Flower

**PS**:

x and y depends on the data obtained from the json file.

The workaround I thought was to, instead of creating an json file, create a .txt file, which contains Json data fragments. Then, save the contents of the  .txt file into a variable. And finally, from that variable select each json data fragments to work with them individually, as if each one were an individual json file.

But, would it have a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to do? From your question it seems you do not understand what is serialization.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand ^^", I spent the day looking for tutorials about Json. But I can only find basic tutorials that show just how to instantiate a specific class from the json file's data. But what I would like is to create instances of different classes from the single json file.
As I said I already looked for various tutorials, official documentation, etc. But I did not see anything about it. So, should I assume that this is impossible then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON structure instead of maintining the count.

```
{
   "AnimalCollection" :
            [
                 { "id":"Animal-1", "IsMammal":true },
                 { "id":"Animal-2", "IsMammal":true },
                 { "id":"Animal-3", "IsMammal":true }
            ],
    "FlowerCollection":
            [
                 { "id":"Flower-1", "numberOfPetals":30 },
                 { "id":"Flower-2", "numberOfPetals":20 },
                 { "id":"Flower-3", "numberOfPetals":10 },
                 { "id":"Flower-4", "numberOfPetals":3 }
            ]
}
```

Then you can deserialize this using newtonsoft.json into below type

```
public class Data
{
    public Animal[] AnimalCollection {get;set;}
    public Flower[] FlowerCollection{get;set;
}
```

It will contain 3 animal instances and 4 flower instances from JSON.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is a simple way to do it. Although not exactly the solution I wanted ^^ "But I think I can adapt it to have the result I'm looking for.
Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to know that this solution helped you !

Answer (score 0):

You can load the JSON file and convert the data into datatable. Create new list of Animal and Flower.

c# code as follows:

```
//Declare typed list of Animals
            List<Animal> AllAnimals = new List<Animal>();

            //Declare typed list of Flowers
            List<Flower> AllFlowers = new List<Flower>();
            DataTable dt;
            //Load JSON file data
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(JSONFilePath))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                //convert JSON data to datatable
                dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
            }
           foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (row[1].ToString() == "Animal")
                {
                    Animal NewAnimal = new Animal();
                    NewAnimal.id = row[0].ToString();
                    NewAnimal.isMammal = row[2].ToString();
                    AllAnimals.Add(NewAnimal);
                }
                else
                {
                    Flower NewFlower = new Flower();
                    NewFlower.id = row[0].ToString();
                    NewFlower.numberOfPetals = row[3].ToString();
                    AllFlowers.Add(NewFlower);
                }
            }
```

Below is a sample of json data that can be loaded from a file:

```
{
    {
   "id": "0",
   "EntryType": "Animal",
   "IsMamal": "True",
   "numberOfPetals": ""
 },
 {
   "id": "1",
   "EntryType": "Animal",
   "IsMamal": "True",
   "numberOfPetals": ""
 },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "EntryType": "Flower",
   "IsMamal": "",
   "numberOfPetals": "8"
 },
 {
   "id": "1",
   "EntryType": "Flower",
   "IsMamal": "",
   "numberOfPetals": "6"
 },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "EntryType": "Flower",
   "IsMamal": "",
   "numberOfPetals": "10"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution would work if I were to implement it in the exact example I gave. But unfortunately that's not the case ^^" the code I intend to implement this logic will use dozens of classes that contain tens or hundreds of variables each. So will be it's difficult to describe all of them in each object in the json file ^^ ". But thanks anyway, I had not considered this kind of solution before, I can sure use you logic for other parts of my system.